# how to update the huge records chunk by chunk

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data around 500 000. I need to update the data of First name and Second name to capital letters

My sample Data :

```
declare @T table(Firstname varchar(max),Secondname varchar(max))
insert into @T values ('ch bhaskar rao ','sridhar kolla ')
insert into @T values ('hemanth kumar','varun chenna-reddy')
insert into @T values ('mohan vara prasad','raju t d p durga raju')
insert into @T values ('police mutual','police mutual')
```

My Script :

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    select (
        select upper(T.N.value('.', 'char(1)')),
            lower(stuff(T.N.value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''))+(CASE WHEN RIGHT(T.N.value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1)='-' THEN '' ELSE ' ' END)
        from X.Secondname.nodes('/N') as T(N)
        for xml path(''), type
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)') As Secondname
    from 
    (
        select 
         cast('<N>'+replace(replace(replace(Secondname, ' ', '</N><N>'),' ', '</N><N>'),'-','-</N><N>')  +'</N>' as xml) as Secondname
        from @T
    ) as X 
)
UPDATE T 
SET
    Secondname = C.Secondname
FROM 
    CTE C 
    INNER JOIN @T T 
        ON   T.Secondname = C.Secondname

Select Secondname from @T
```

It is working fine when data is around 10 000 records but system getting hanged up when I'm trying to update huge records around 5 millions. How to update chunk by chunk like 10000 and again 10000, so that system will not burdened?

Comment: Don't use varchar(max) for names. Varchar(100) should probably be long enough for every first or last name on the planet.

Comment: xml path is too slow approch;

Comment: please read question carefully forget about XML I'm asking about how to update in chunks when we are dealing with huge records @SanuAntony

Comment: @TT. - `1 million` = `10 lakhs`. It is used in India

Comment: @VR46 =) Oh, good to know. So he has half a million rows.

Comment: @VR46 we are habituated to lakhs :) so now half a million

Comment: @VR46 so I will add the columns in new table but then how I need to update in chunks as I'm really unable to move forward

Answer (score 1):

considering `@t` table is a physical table in your database.

This approach will have minimal logging.

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT (SELECT Upper(T.N.value('.', 'char(1)')),
                        Lower(Stuff(T.N.value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')) + ( CASE
                                                                                     WHEN RIGHT(T.N.value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1) = '-' THEN ''
                                                                                     ELSE ' '
                                                                                   END )
                 FROM   X.Secondname.nodes('/N') AS T(N)
                 FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)') AS Secondname
         FROM   (SELECT Cast('<N>'
                             + Replace(Replace(Replace(Secondname, ' ', '</N><N>'), ' ', '</N><N>'), '-', '-</N><N>')
                             + '</N>' AS XML) AS Secondname
                 FROM   @T) AS X)

select  ISNULL(C.Secondname,T.Secondname) into TEMP_TABLE
FROM   CTE C
       RIGHT JOIN @T T
               ON T.Secondname = C.Secondname
```

recreate your index and constraints in new temp_table

Now rename the temp_table to old table name

```
exec sp_rename original_table, original_table_bck -- to rename the original table name to another name 
exec sp_rename temp_table, original_table
```

Comment: I have given sample data but that table have lot of columns and Indexes in the main Database it will create impact on rest of the functionality. can you tell me anything more specific instead of dropping or renaming

Comment: @mohan111 You can add all the column in new table. Alternatively you can use While loop or cursor to update the records in chunk's

Comment: so I will add the columns in new table but then how I need to update in chunks as I'm really unable to move forward @VR46

Comment: @mohan111 - You don't have to update.. Just rename the temp table to original table name

Answer (score 1):

You can update the table in chunks like mentioned below:

```
declare @i int = 2
declare @j int = 1

    while @j > 0 
        begin 
            begin transaction
            update top (@i) a
            set a.firstname = upper(a.firstname),
                a.secondname = upper(a.secondname)
            from aa as a
            where a.firstname collate latin1_general_cs_as <> upper(a.firstname)
            set @j = @@rowcount
            commit transaction

        end
```

you can change the above code as per your needs. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to update the starting character of first name and last name in Database? You can handle it in CSS while you are displaying it by using

```
text-transform: capitalize;
```

Comment: this is not to show in front End we need to insert into data into Scribe tool

Answer (score -1):

Try this; this will help you in resolving the issue
Run the function below and then

```
SELECT dbo.InitCap
       (Firstname
       ), dbo.InitCap
       (Secondname
       )
FROM @t;

IF OBJECT_ID('InitCap') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION InitCap;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[InitCap]
                               (
                @InputString VARCHAR(4000)
                               )
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS
     BEGIN
         DECLARE @Index INT;
         DECLARE @Char CHAR(1);
         DECLARE @PrevChar CHAR(1);
         DECLARE @OutputString VARCHAR(255);
         SET @OutputString = LOWER(@InputString);
         SET @Index = 1;
         WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
             BEGIN
                 SET @Char = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1);
                 SET @PrevChar = CASE
                                     WHEN @Index = 1
                                     THEN ' '
                                     ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index-1, 1)
                                 END;
                 IF @PrevChar IN
                                 (' ', ';', ':', '!', '?', ',', '.', '_', '-', '/', '&', '''', '('
                                 )
                     BEGIN
                         IF @PrevChar != ''''
                            OR UPPER(@Char) != 'S'
                             SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString, @Index, 1, UPPER(@Char));
                     END;
                 SET @Index = @Index + 1;
             END;
         RETURN @OutputString;
     END;
GO
```