# how to handle & character in XML Format

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have some sample data like

```
CREATE TABLE #Employee
(Id INT, Name NVARCHAR(100), Status TINYINT)
GO
INSERT INTO #Employee ( Id, Name, Status)
Values (1, '&Basavaraj Biradar', 0),
        (2, 'Shree Biradar', 0),
        (3, '&Kalpana Biradar', 0),
        (4, '& ', 0)
GO
```

when there are no special characters it is coming fine but when characters like - or &. it is not coming

error showing as

```
Msg 9411, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
XML parsing: line 1, character 14, semicolon expected
```

my query is like this :

```
select cast('<N>'+replace(replace(replace(Name, ' ', '</N><N>'),' ', '</N><N>'),'-','-</N><N>')  +'</N>' as xml) from #Employee
```

when name is having normal string it is working fine but not for Special characters.
Suggest me

Comment: Please tell us what would be your expected output based on the given data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Employee
(Id INT, Name NVARCHAR(100), Status TINYINT)
GO
INSERT INTO #Employee ( Id, Name, Status)
Values (1, '&Basavaraj Biradar', 0),
        (2, 'Shree Biradar', 0),
        (3, '&Kalpana Biradar', 0),
        (4, '& ', 0)
GO

select cast('<N>'+replace(replace(Name,'&','&amp;'), ' ', '</N><N>')  +'</N>' as xml) from #Employee

--DROP TABLE #Employee
```

Comment: actually this is also I have looked into but my problem I just want to make them first letter to capital in full name as I have achieved but when the script is not working when & comes please refer to this question of mine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474766/how-to-update-the-huge-records-chunk-by-chunk

Comment: You are mixing two things... On SO it is common sense, that each question should be focused on one problem. This question is "How to handle "&" in XML and you've got a solution for this. Now you've got a second question, not even mentioned above. Even your given sample data is all correctly capitalized. So please: If *this* question is solved vote all usefull contributions up and tick one answer as accepted. Then start a new question with fitting sample data and expected output and place a link as comment here. The helping armada gets on a *new* question like wesps on a plum cake...

Answer (score 2):

The ampersand is a special character in in XML, so you'll need to escape it. Use `&amp;` instead.

Following the pattern from your existing code, replace `Name` field reference with `replace(Name, '&', '&amp;')`

The updated query is

```
select cast('<N>'+replace(replace(replace( replace( Name, '&', '&amp;')  , ' ', '</N><N>'),' ', '</N><N>'),'-','-</N><N>')  +'</N>' as xml) from #Employee
```

and I get this as the result

```
<N>&amp;Basavaraj</N><N>Biradar</N> 
<N>Shree</N><N>Biradar</N>
<N>&amp;Kalpana</N><N>Biradar</N> 
<N>&amp;</N><N />
```

Comment: yes I have tried with the same replace function but with no success just try with my sample data in your machine

Comment: I think this is useful, therefore I voted it up, and you were a bit faster than me which should be honored ... :-)

Comment: @mohan111 I tried this with your query and it worked.

Comment: yeah @BabakNaffas this one is useful